# validate end date using start date in laravel 5 using request class

Tags: laravel-5

This is my request class.

```
public function rules()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    return [
        'title' => 'required|unique:event_cals,title',
        'eventDate' => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
        'endDate'   => 'date|before:event_cals,' . date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $input['eventDate'] . ' +1 day' ) ),
        'venue' => 'required',
        'time' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'photo' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:1000'
    ];
}

public function messages(){
    return [
        'title.required' => 'Title is required.',
        'title.unique' => 'Title is already there.',
        'eventDate.after' => 'Event Date is passed.',
        'eventDate.required' => 'Event Date is required.',
        'venue.required' => 'Venue is required.',
        'time.required' => 'Time is required.',
        'type.required' => 'Type is required.',
        'endDate.date' => 'Due Date should be after starting date',

    ];
}
```

There I want to verify whether endDate is after the eventDate. It is working properly except when endDate is similar to eventDate. But I want to make sure that there must be able to add an endDate which is similar to eventDate also. For an example if the eventDate is 03/04/2016, there can be able to add an endDate as 03/04/2016 or any upcoming date. But from above rule 03/04/2016 is invalid as an endDate. Is there any keyword for before or equal? Please can any one help me figure out this mess?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting the input before you establish the `$rules`, you can try adding one day to `eventDate` before validation:

```
$rules = [
    'eventDate' => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
    'endDate'   => 'date|before:event_cals,' . date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $input['eventDate'] . ' +1 day' ) ),
];
```

Or you can extend Laravel to create a new validation rule that handles this for you (and makes it easier to reuse in other controllers).

Comment: $input makes an error as undefined. How to fix that?

Comment: Fix using ```$input = Input::all();```. You should replace ```$input``` whatever you are storing the input values in.

Comment: I have updated the answer above. For any values of endDate it will display an error. Where am I wrong?

Comment: If you are trying to verify `endDate` is after `eventDate`, you need to use `after` rule, not `before`.

Comment: when I used after any endDate can be added. Where am I wrong again?

Comment: According to your original question: `There I want to verify whether endDate is after the eventDate`, which means that any date after eventDate would be valid. Is that not what you're after?